# How to use Evernote developer token in javascript

Tags: javascript, api, evernote, apex

I want to create notes to my personal evernote account. So I guess for this I have to use developer token. But the question is how can I use this developer token in javascript or apex. What URL should I use?

Can someone please post a code snippet for this? I have developer token and URL something like this:

S=s313:U=3f70651:E=14tcfe653f4:C=542783809f7:P=1cd:A=en-devtoken:V=2:H=5yb823a1zv54d7f8b61536artva19d79

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s313/notestore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evernote has Javascript SDK for its [API](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js/) and the sample code is [here](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js/blob/master/sample/client/EDAMTest.js). Note that you shouldn't reveal your token since anyone can access your own notes with it. I recommend you revoke your current token and create new one. You can revoke it from [here](https://www.evernote.com/AuthorizedServices.action). It should appear as "Evernote Developer Token.

Comment: Thanks, no worries I had changed the values in the token. however I need to run the apex code as a scheduled job so can I call javascript in apex class instead of apex page?

Comment: I'm not familiar with apex. If it's similar environment to Node.js, it may work. Otherwise, you may need to deal with thrift libraries to make it work.